# How can I migrate a WSL2 filesystem to a HyperV or VirtualBox VM?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have an existing Ubuntu 18.04 WSL2 installation on my Windows 10 machine. I want to start using a linux VM instead of WSL2 instead but I don't want to set up my VM from scratch again. Is there some way I can use the underlying vhdx in a WSL2 installation to seed the root file system of a new linux VM in Hyper-V or VirtualBox?

Comment: You can try exporting the VHDX and mount it to VM. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/412
I haven't tried it myself, but it is worth checking.